# CSS - which code renders faster and is more efficient?

Tags: css, performance

I would like to know which of below codes renders faster and is more efficient:

This -

```
body{background:#ddd;font-family:verdana;font-size:12px;color:#808080;}
a{color:#808080;outline:0;text-decoration:none;}
input{margin:0;padding:0;font-family:verdana;color:#808080;}
ul{padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Or this -

```
body,input{font-family:verdana}
body,input,a{color:#808080;}
body{background:#ddd;;font-size:12px;}
a{outline:0;text-decoration:none;}
input,ul{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Efficiency is irrelevant here.

Go with whichever is easier to read/understand/maintain, which is clearly the first snippet.

However, that second snippet looks like it's been [minified](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#MinifyCSS), which is a good thing to do, because it reduces the transfer size of the CSS - it doesn't improve the "rendering speed".

You should write your CSS in the most understandable way, then generate a minified version when you put it live.

Comment: how is rendering efficiency is irrelevant here?
check out this website:
http://forr.st/posts/CSS_Rendering_Speed_Grouping_Selectors_vs_Prop-T4S
they say that code number 2 will probably render faster - why? because it has less selectors
it is probably true that a minified code is better because - rendering speed depends on browser speed and computer speed
The conclusion-the method of which is better depends on four things - computer speed, browser speed and internet connect (which are irrelevant to the programmer, but the main thing is that it depends on the number of css elements,am i right?

Comment: I don't have any numbers (I just don't care enough to benchmark), but it's irrelevant here because the difference (for an average sized page) is probably less than a millisecond. What can make slightly more difference is writing [efficient selectors](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors). So bear in mind selector efficiency and minify your CSS (only to reduce transfer size). 99% of sites don't need anything more when it comes to CSS "performance".

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen any performance issue with CSS, except one thing. When you use `*` in some cases your JavaScript can become very slow.